# 100% width video and 500px height

Tags: css, video

I need to set 100% width video and 500px height. Is there any chance for this ? I checked posts on this site and found just code on 100% background:

```
#video_background {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                z-index: -1000;
                background: url(assets/picture.jpg) no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                overflow: hidden;
                }
```

Comment: Doesn't setting `width:100%;` and `height:500px;` works?

Comment: Can we see your HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nicely explained article.

https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

You can either set `<video width="100%" ...` or in CSS set

```
#video_background{
  width: 100%    !important;
  height: auto   !important;
}
```

Comment: What you ment by "does not work". You want to cut out the part below the 500px? Then why not wrap it in a div and make the overflow hidden?